# Anonymous access for SharePoint Views with Paging and Sorting

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, anonymous-access

I have a SharePoint Publishing site with document library views added , when the anonymous users are trying to do sorting or to move to next page using paging they are prompted for credentials.

Is there a way to get rid of this issue and make this Paging and sorting workable for the Anonymous users.

Tried Solutions :

1. Enabling Server Side Rendering in Views (cannot use this as I need
   Client Side rendering)
2. Disabling **Limited-access user permission lockdown mode** (Cannot
   use this as disabling this feature will allow anonymous users to access
   all the application pages)

Any suggestions on this is highly appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can enable or disable anonymous access for a web application. If you enable anonymous access for a web application, site administrators can then grant or deny anonymous access at the site collection, site, or item level. If anonymous access is disabled for a web application, no sites within that web application can be accessed by anonymous users.

References:

[Manage anonymous access for a web application in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/manage-anonymous-access-for-a-web-application)

[How to enable anonymous access in SharePoint 2016/2013](https://www.spguides.com/anonymous-site-in-sharepoint-2013-or-sharepoint-2016/)

Comment: Anonymous access has been given and the users can access the site anonymously , the issue here is when we show the document library views to them with paging/sorting anonymous users are prompted for credentials . this is because the actions paging and sorting needs access to  /_layouts/inplview.aspx. application page . which is restricted if we enable Limited-access user permission lockdown mode feature in the site . so i need help here to handle this.